# How to hide columns for which rows do not hold any data in devextreme react grid?

Tags: reactjs, devextreme

I am using https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/ for a data table, I have column visibility filter, and hundreds of rows and around 15 columns. I want to hide those columns for which any row does not have any data. How can I do this without manually checking every row against every column (`O(n^2)`)and creating a map and using that info? Any direct attribute or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Column Visibility`](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/column-visibility/).

> A Grid component with the [TableColumnVisibility](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/reference/table-column-visibility/) and [ColumnChooser](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/reference/column-chooser/) plugins provides the capability to hide or show table columns at runtime.

But this you need to check which column don't have any value for all rows and once you get all those column, you just need to pass props inside of `TableColumnVisibility`. Please check below example

**Code Snippet**

```
render() {
    const { rows, columns } = this.state;
    //Check if all column value is blak for all row then need to push value in hiddenColumnNames.
    let hiddenColumnNames = columns.reduce((r,v)=>{
      if(!rows.find(obj=>obj[v.name] !== "")){
        r.push(v.name);
      }
      return r;
    },[]);//Hidden column will be [age,city]

    return (
      <Paper>
        <Grid rows={rows} columns={columns}>
          <Table />
          <TableHeaderRow />
          <TableColumnVisibility
          hiddenColumnNames={hiddenColumnNames}
        />
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
```

You can check here with working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/devextreme-react-grid-for-material-ui-38lxn)

Comment: Visibility is one thing, but I was asking about completely removing those columns form view even visibility menu, I did that by setting a map with column name and value count, and filtered the ones with zero value. I was checking if we have some direct attribute or other control for this purpose!

Comment: As per that you question, you are asking `how to hide` and there is attribute that will be hide the column. That is fulfill your requirement. Again if you don't want the use that property then you could pass only those columns that have all rows value `columns={columns}`. Like this `columns = columns.reduce((r,v)=>{
          if(rows.find(obj=>obj[v.name] !== "")){
            r.push(v.name);
          }
          return r;
        },[]);//only show this columns column will be columns`